# UWP MapRouteFinder Throwing Errors

Tags: uwp

I am trying to get started wit UWP MapControl but specifically the MapRouteFinder.
I have tried this code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/routes-and-directions

```
        //   Get the route between the points.
        MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
              await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(
              new Geopoint(startLocation),
              new Geopoint(endLocation),
              MapRouteOptimization.Time,
              MapRouteRestrictions.None);
```

unfortunately I am gettin a build error thus:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS4036  'IAsyncOperation<MapRouteFinderResult>' does not contain a 
definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a 
first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<MapRouteFinderResult>' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)
```

Not sure what missing a using directive for 'System'? means.

Comment: Have you added `async` keyword  in the  method ?

Comment: Yes I did - The problem is that it's a UWP only Control.

Comment: Strange, could you mind share a mini sample?